# Extract And Save mysql data

Tags: java, mysql, etl

I have a data is about 30-40GB and it represents as XML and stored as BLOB in MySQL server.
I want to create a new table, that should parse the XML and extract particular attributes to store as different columns(10-20 columns).

Is there any good ETL tool is available to do this?

NOTE: Currently i am simply using JDBC and Java to this transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Talend Open Studio for data integration.](https://www.talend.com/download/) You will need to use the tFileInputXML component to read the file, you can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyoMfdHA1fc) out. The result from this component can be processed and loaded into your database using a tMySQLOutput or tOracleOutput or any other database input component.